# How to quit all apps/all apps from workspace?

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, workspaces

I can't find anywhere the gnome action of "quit all open applications" - which seems strange as it's such an obvious thing to do.

Does it exist in gnome (or anywhere - in wayland/xorg/system), so I can set it?

If not, then what is the correct command to bind to a shortcut to close gracefully all apps? Do I need to do it low level with signals?

And lastly: how would I modify the solution to only close applications on a specific workspace or set of workspaces? (i refer to gnome workspaces)

Comment: I'm also not aware of such an action, but is logging out an option for you?

Comment: no, usually when I want to use that is when I'm done with work and want to just get rid of it out of my eyes quickly ;) but don't quit computer

Comment: I don't think it is that simple. You can have applications that need user assistance to close properly. For example you can have a virtual machine running doing some process. Or the file manager copying or moving data. Closing applications forcefully without caring of what they are doing may cause loss of data or other problems, and that seems a reason enough why a desktop such as Gnome won't ship that option.

Comment: @schrodingerscatcuriosity but zaabson is right, there *is* a mechanism for that, which is why Libreoffice asks you to save the current document once you click "logout" in GNOME. So, the mechanisms are in place! Your programs get the "hey, user wants to sign out" signal, and they can inhibit the execution of the sign out for as long as they want.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I understand that point of view, but it may depend too much on each specific application, what process is performing and how graceful and transparent it behaves on such signals. Nautilus, which is Gnome's, can be very erratic when trying to close it if it's copying data for example.

Comment: @schrodingerscatcuriosity I don't know nautilus well enough to comment on that, but that's also besides the point, I'd say!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I guess it can be debatable. OP asks for Gnome and from the point of view of a desktop user, looking for a feature that Gnome could/should provide. From the developer point of view, adding such feature knowing what a can of worms it could be, and taking into account that users can have very different needs and expectations on such behaviour that ultimately is not necessary and arguably in the best interest of the user... I at least wouldn't put much effort on it. It would be interesting to know if some desktop, wm, etc has ever provided a feature like this.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I mentioned Nautilus beacause it's Gnome's, and if one of Gnome's base apps can't be closed (graphically) without problems in some cases, imagine adding that as a global feature.

Comment: @schrodingerscatcuriosity I get that, but that's the point – zaabson does *not* want to close nautilus "graphically"; they want to send a session-wide signal for it to close once it's done. And as far as I can tell, that actually does work!

Comment: But come on, is there some special mechanism when I click "alt+f4" or the window close button? 
I'd like a shortcut that's semantically equivalent to clicking "alt+f4" as long as there's applications to quit. That is: I do "quit all", and then sequantialy choose action in all of the application popups ("save"/"dont save" etc.) for all of the application that I quit.

Why is this debatable?

Comment: @zaabson What I think is debatable is not the need of it or how practical it is. You state *"I can't find anywhere the gnome action of "quit all open applications" - which seems strange as it's such an obvious thing to do."*, so, why does Gnome doesn't have this feature. I don't think is strange because from a developer's point of view is not as easy as "pressing alt+F4". You have to think on all use cases, the user behaviour and the application's behaviour and the hardware behaviour. →

Comment: @zaabson → Yes, could be practical, yes, could be doable, but does it deserve time spent in development, and in FOSS? And again, does any OS/desktop/etc implements something like this?